# Does pip provide a TOML parser for python 3.9?

Tags: python, pip, python-import, toml

I want to parse TOML files in python 3.9, and I am wondering if I can do so without installing another package.

Since `pip` knows how to work with `pyproject.toml` files, and I already have `pip` installed, does `pip` provide a parser that I can import and use in my own code?

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that `pip` has access to a parser; it doesn't really *provide* it, in the sense that you are welcome to use it.

Comment: I think I understand. Although one can access it, and one can parse TOML files with it, the TOML parser inside `pip` is only for its internal use. I still like knowing because (a) MacGyver, and (b) I learn more about how python packages are managed and how "batteries included" is achieved.

Comment: Keep in mind: Python 3.11 now has a TOML parser in the standard library, so `pip` may stop providing a vendored parser in the future.

Comment: (The above is my opinion; I have no knowledge of what the `pip` maintainers may be planning.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 3.9, `pip` vendors [tomli](https://pypi.org/project/tomli/):

```
from pip._vendor import tomli
```

For [consenting adults](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html), importing the vendored module [should work as usual](https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/main/src/pip/_vendor#vendoring-policy). However, this is an *implementation detail* of pip, and it could change without a deprecation period at any moment in a future release of pip. Therefore, for anything apart from a quick hack, it would be safer to install `tomli` (or some other TOML parser) into the site instead.

Comment: And even `pip` will prefer a properly installed version of `tomli` to its vendored package if available.

Comment: @chepner Hmm, are you sure? I don't see evidence of that. It would seem to defeat the purpose of vendoring.

Comment: Oh, I was looking at a section in `pip._vendor` which only does the conditional import of the vendored code if a redistribution has explicitly patched `pip._vendor.DEBUNDLED` to be true. It uses a `vendored` function that tries to install a package normally before patching the vendored version into place. (I assumed the vendored version was just a backup of last resort.)

Answer (score 2):

So, it seems that PIP vendors the toml library [`tomli`](https://pypi.org/project/tomli/). Just after searching for "pyproject.toml" in the pip github repo, I found the [following function in the source code:](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/8dbb8b9bbe4976c87e465695850821804aa47a83/src/pip/_internal/pyproject.py#L29):

```
def load_pyproject_toml(
    use_pep517: Optional[bool], pyproject_toml: str, setup_py: str, req_name: str
) -> Optional[BuildSystemDetails]:
    """Load the pyproject.toml file.
    Parameters:
        use_pep517 - Has the user requested PEP 517 processing? None
                     means the user hasn't explicitly specified.
        pyproject_toml - Location of the project's pyproject.toml file
        setup_py - Location of the project's setup.py file
        req_name - The name of the requirement we're processing (for
                   error reporting)
    Returns:
        None if we should use the legacy code path, otherwise a tuple
        (
            requirements from pyproject.toml,
            name of PEP 517 backend,
            requirements we should check are installed after setting
                up the build environment
            directory paths to import the backend from (backend-path),
                relative to the project root.
        )
    """
    has_pyproject = os.path.isfile(pyproject_toml)
    has_setup = os.path.isfile(setup_py)

    if not has_pyproject and not has_setup:
        raise InstallationError(
            f"{req_name} does not appear to be a Python project: "
            f"neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found."
        )

    if has_pyproject:
        with open(pyproject_toml, encoding="utf-8") as f:
            pp_toml = tomli.loads(f.read())
    ...
```

The `tomli` import at [the top:](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/8dbb8b9bbe4976c87e465695850821804aa47a83/src/pip/_internal/pyproject.py#L6)

```
from pip._vendor import tomli
```

Checking in the REPL

```
>>> from pip._vendor import tomli
>>> tomli.loads('[foo]\nbar = "baz"')
{'foo': {'bar': 'baz'}}
```

Of course, this is not part of the public API, and you should *really* not rely on this.

Comment: Thanks for the details, teaching me how to fish. For anyone who has the same question for other versions of python, I went poking around on my pc: versions `3.7`, `3.9`, `3.10`, `3.11` all installed with `pip._vendor.tomli` while version `3.8` had `pip._vendor.toml`. The difference brings home your point about not relying on it, in addition to it not being intended. Python `3.11` includes `tomllib` in the standard library, so no point snooping inside `pip` for it.